# $inc mongoose not incrementing value

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making an beg command for my discord bot, but $inc isn't incrementing the value!
I also have this issue for my warn command. I have to mention though that I'm not very experienced with mongodb

My code is:

```js
const schema = require('../schemas/moneyschema')
 
module.exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
 
    const givers = [
        "Elon Musk",
        "Jeff Bezos",
        "Your Crush",
        "Mike Oxlong"
    ]
 
    const giver = givers[Math.floor(Math.random() * givers.length)]
    const givenMoney = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501)
 
    if (schema.findOne({ _id: msg.author.id })) {
        schema.updateOne({ $inc: { "money": givenMoney } })
        msg.reply(`${giver} gave you $${givenMoney}`)
    } else {
        let newData = new schema({
            _id: msg.author.id,
            money: givenMoney
        })
 
        newData.save()
        msg.reply(`${giver} gave you your first $${givenMoney}`)
    }
 
}
 
module.exports.help = {
    name: "beg",
    aliases: []
}
```

Is there anyone that is experienced with mongodb and knows how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose will not predict for which guild it should increment the field for.
You haven't specified a filter which is the first argument in the `updateOne` method in mongoose. You can read about this [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne)

```js
        schema.updateOne({_id: msg.author.id},{ $inc: { "money": givenMoney } })
```

should fix it